# Using XML to communicate with a server

Tags: xml

I'm working on a project which involves writing a program to communicate with a server, using XML over a TCP/IP connection. I am quite new to the programming world and have no experience in XML. All i know is that it's a little like HTML, which i have used many years ago. The only thing I was told is that the program must be in XML in order for the server to understand the messages i'm sending.

I wanted to know where i can start programming. Are there any programs out there which will allow me to code in XML and then compile the code for execution? Do i need a program to write the code or is there any other way?

Any help will be much appreciated since i really dont know where to start with.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot program in XML. Its a data format not a programming language.

Comment: If you say what language you'll be using to program it might help get some answers.  For instance, I send XML messages to a server using a program written in C#.  What programming language and platform will you be using?

Answer (score 1):

As John Saunders said in the comments, XML is a data format. Per programming, you'll have to get the specifics of the TCP connection. What protocol and port? Then you'll need to get a schema for the XML document - this will describe the format of the XML you'll be sending. After you get specifics about the communications, you should be able to formulate questions specific to the language you choose. Ditto the XML.

Comment: I didn't know XML was a data format and not a programming language. The program I'm using for a big chunk of my work is Matlab. I have the IP address and port of the server and have been able to establish a connection with the server using Matlab. However, I'm not too confident about the connection unless i can send and receive an acknowledgment from the server. For that I need to send and receive XML messages. I have the schema i believe. So all i need to figure out is how to send/receive XML messages using Matlab, right?

Comment: i am not familiar with how matlab works, but yes, you either need to figure out how to send a message from matlab or how to export xml from it and send it with something else. if it can't export xml, but can export something else, you could export that other format and write code to convert it to xml.